# issue displaying byte array to bitmap to fetch an image in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, arrays

I'm having problem converting byte array to bitmap. Now what I'm trying to achieve is I'm getting image as a byte array and trying to convert into bitmap so that I can display the image. but after running my below code in my **bitmap output** i'm getting **Null value**.

```
String t= "byte array of the image";
byte[] temp = t.getBytes() ;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp, 0, temp.length);
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
System.out.println("bitmap output"+bmp);
```

I have googled a lot and found this code works for every1. can please someone tell me where I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
In my case this is working

String result = "here imge;

if (result != "") {
byte[] bloc = Base64.decode(result); 
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8; 
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bloc, 0, bloc.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
String t= "byte array of the image";

byte[] temp = Base64.decode(t, Base64.NO_WRAP); //UPDATE HERE

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp, 0, temp.length);
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
System.out.println("bitmap output"+bmp);
```